# DynamoDB parameterized PartiQL query with executeStatement

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, partiql

I have the following query with the aws sdk in nodejs and running in aws lamdba that doesn't work when using the parameters array:

```
executeStatement({ 
  Statement: `select * from "myTable"."myIndex" where "pk" = '?' and "sortKey5" >= 50 ORDER BY "sortKey5" DESC`,
  Parameters: [{"S": pk}] })
```

the same query with the parameter directly inline works

```
executeStatement({ 
 Statement: `select * from "myTable"."myIndex" where "pk" = 'xxx' and "sortKey5" >= 50 ORDER BY "sortKey5" DESC` })
```

it's probably the syntax with '?' that is wrong but I couldn't find any sample with an other syntax.

does any one knows how to write the statement so that it uses the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that, at least in a SELECT statement, one needs to omit the single-quotes around the `?`, e.g. `foobar = ?` rather than `foobar = '?'`.

So your query would be:

```js
executeStatement({ 
  Statement: `select * from "myTable"."myIndex" where "pk" = ? and "sortKey5" >= 50 ORDER BY "sortKey5" DESC`,
  Parameters: [{"S": pk}]
})
```